# "Team meat" or "Meat team"

Tags: word-order

Based on what I know from English grammar, team should come after the name. The examples are "Soccer Team", "Basketball team", etc.. But recently I've seen some indie developers naming themselves as "Team [name]". Team Meat is an example of that, or [Team Snore](http://en.teamsnore.com/). And watching a commentary, I've heard them say "Team Na'Vi" or "Team Orange". So I was wondering if such an structure is acceptable or not?

Comment: It's a title/name, not a sentence, and hence strictly it does not have to be grammatical. Names such as "Team XYZ" are not uncommon.

Comment: "Team Na'Vi" is a Dota 2 team. (Just trying to give an example of both uses in one sentence.)

Answer (score 5):

OP's examples aren't really [postposed adjectives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposition_and_postposition) in the normal sense. As discussed by [British linguist David Crystal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Crystal) in his blog entry [On Team GB](http://david-crystal.blogspot.co.uk/2008/08/on-team-gb.html), this ["**restrictive apposition**"](http://stylemanual.ngs.org/home/A/apposition) construction is essentially the same as...

> ***Mount Everest*** (= the mountain that is Everest)
>    ***Queen Elizabeth*** (= the Queen who is Elizabeth)
>    my ***brother Fred*** (= my brother who is Fred)
>    the ***number six*** (= the number that is six)
>    ***Hurricane Katrina*** (etc., etc.)

That's to say, ***Team Meat = the team which is, more specifically, Meat***. As Crystal puts it, the superficially "reversed word order ... does have a certain rhetorical punch", making it attractive when you want an "imposing" name for your team/whatever.

Personally, I think there's also an argument for saying that to some extent the prepositioned "noun" (***team***, in OP's case) actually functions both grammatically and semantically as an *adjective*. The primary "identifier" of the entity is ***Meat***, which is specifically qualified as being *a type of **team***.

Comment: +1 I first remember this construction in the mid-1980s, specifically "Team USA" for the 1984 US Olympic team. It appears from [this](https://www.casetext.com/case/team-cent-inc-v-xerox-corp/) case involving Xerox' use of "Team Xerox" in a 1983-4 advertising campaign that the use was "derived mainly from European athletic usage" (p.1414).

Comment: @StoneyB: I don't really understand why this one was migrated from ELU, whereas [Why must 'galore' be used postpositively?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/126107/) wasn't. It seems to me these are really two "related, but different" constructions, and it's not obvious to me why one would be thought more relevant to *learners* than the other.

Answer (score 1):

A basketball team is a type of team, i.e. a team that plays basketball.

Team Meat is the name of a team. So, Team Meat is a specific instance of a team. It doesn't tell you what they do.

Comment: I don't see how this "explains" the usage. So far as I'm aware, *Team GB* is normally only used to identify the ***Olympics** team from Great Britain* - but that one doesn't tell you what the team actually *do*, and it could equally well be referred to as *[the] GB team*.

Comment: I don't think anyone would refer to the Great British team as GB team. Your brackets are incorrect, an article is always required. Team Meat is a name of a team, not a type of team.

Comment: Your comment presupposes a specific [grammatical/semantic] role for my square brackets. I know in some [particularly, *computer-related*] usages it denotes an *optional but not required* element, but that wasn't particularly my intention there. I personally wouldn't have any problem referring to ***our** GB team*, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Team - Shashank is an acceptable structure . It indicates that the team is named as shashank . Soccer team , basketball team are the types of teams and not the name of the team per-se.